# Does the centre of mass of a circular object such as a cylinder or sphere rotate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, angular-velocity

Say I pushed a cylinder to roll on a flat surface with velocity *v*, the point at contact with the floor will have zero velocity in order for the cylinder to not slip - which implies the point at contact with the floor has zero angular velocity. By applying the equation, *w*=v/R, the point at the centre of mass of the cylinder should rotate. However, if I use a marker to draw a line connecting the centre of the cylinder to the bottom of the cylinder on the side of the cylinder, and look at the cylinder roll from a side view, it looks like the centre of the cylinder is not rotating and that the point that was at contact with the floor rolled.

Comment: You have to be careful with how you apply the equation $\omega=\frac vR$. The velocity of the contact point is $0$ relative to the ground, but it still has an angular velocity about the center of the cylinder. It seems like your confusion lies in the use of this formula and switching between reference frames.

Answer (score 2):

the center of mass does rotate but only in the contact point's frame of reference, not to yours